What values can the Betti numbers of an orientable manifold take?
This question is very naive, but here we go anyway: Let $M$ be an orientable manifold and let $b_i$, for $i=0,1 \dots, n=\mathrm{dim}(M)$ be its Betti numbers. Poincaré duality tells us that $b_i = b_{n-i}$. At this level of generality are there any other restrictions on the values of $b_i$? For any sequence of integers $a_0,a_1, \dots, a_{m}$, with $m=n/2$ for $m$ even, and $m=(n-1)/2$, for $m$ odd, can we find a manifold with these Betti numbers? Surely not!

Have you seen this question?

I  asked myself this question  years ago and I do not have  a satisfactory answer yet.  There are  some restrictions given by the Poincare duality namely $b_{n-i}=b_i$. Additionally, if  $\dim M=4k+2$,  then the middle Betti number $b_{2k+1}$ must be even. In odd dimensions and  dimensions $4k+2$ these are the only constraints.  More generally, if $n=2k$,   $b_k$ is even,  and $b_{n-i}=b_i$, $\forall i$, then there exist an oriented manifold  of dimension $2k$ with these Betti numbers. Weird things happen in dimensions $4k$.
As  discussed in Remark 7.2.15 of these notes  there is no $12$-dimensional manifold with Poincaré polynomial $1+t^6+t^{12}$ and no $20$-dimensional manifold  with Poincaré polynomial $1+t^{10}+t^{20}$. This is a consequence of Hirzebruch's signature formula and some   strange divisibility properties involving  Bernoulli numbers.

It's still an open question for which powers of 2 there exist a manifold with cohomology ring $\Bbb Q[x]/x^3$ with degree of $x = 2^n$. https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.07892 // It is reduced to a number-theoretic problem, but this problem is pretty far out of reach of known methods.
